# Como conectar el servicio de Windows con Windows Form

Tags: c#

Tengo un servicio que lee errores de disco, espacio de disco, mirar antivirus, etc... (El servicio funcionaria siempre aun que no este abierto el Windows Forms) Pues lo que me interesa por ejemplo es que esos datos me los muestre en el Windows Form para que el usuario que tenga instalado mi programa lo pueda entender sin problemas.

Gracias

Comment: No he entendido nada de lo que has escrito. ¿Qué servicio? ¿Qué hace dicho servicio? ¿Qué tiene que ver dicho servicio con Windows Forms? ¿Por qué Windows Forms y no otra cosa? ¿Por qué Windows Forms es la manera de hacer las cosas legibles para el usuario? ¿Cuáles son tus criterios para determinar que algo es o no es legible?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Vale te explico con mas detalle, tengo un servicio que lee errores de disco, espacio de disco, mirar antivirus, etc... Pues lo que me interesa por ejemplo es que esos datos me los muestre en el Windows Form para que el usuario que tenga instalado mi programa lo pueda entender

Comment: Y donde guarda ese Servicio toda esa informacion? El servicio supongo que aunque no este el Windows Form abierto seguirá almacenando la información y cuando se abra dicho Windows Form se recuperara toda la informacion que se tiene hasta el momento??

Comment: @Capt.Teach Si estoy aquí preguntado para que me podáis recomendar la mejor opción, y si el servicio lee todo el rato aun que no este abierto y el Windows Form muestra dichos datos

Comment: Una manera sencilla que yo haría es siempre guardar la información en un archivo, .txt, .json , .xml (lo que quieras vamos) y cuando se abra el Windows Form leer de ese archivo y mostrarlo como mas te convenga (Toda la información, la información por día , en tiempo real, etc)

Comment: @Capt.Teach si esta opción la tenia presente, pero estuve leyendo sobre WCF pero entiendo que eso es un servio en la web no? Sabes tu algo?

Comment: Personalmente no se lo que es mas allá de la documentación de [microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf) entonces en ese aspecto no te puedo decir nada, seguro que otro usuario puede aclararte esa duda. PD: Toda esta información que has ido diciendo te sugiero que la reflejes en tu pregunta para que la gente no tenga que leer todos los comentarios y así tener una pregunta de mejor calidad . Puedes editar tu pregunta usando [edit]. Un saludo